# What is wrong with this vhdl code for bcd addition?

Tags: vhdl, addition, bcd

The following code is for bcd addition of two numbers. Whenever I input some values, the output for most significant 4-bits comes out to be incorrect(X). I don't know where I am wrong in this.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity bcd_adder1 is
    port(a,b : in  unsigned(3 downto 0);
         c_in : in std_logic;
         sum  : out  unsigned(3 downto 0); 
         c_out : out std_logic);
end bcd_adder1;

architecture func of bcd_adder1 is
begin
process(a,b)
variable sum_temp : unsigned(4 downto 0);
begin
    sum_temp := ('0' & a) + ('0' & b) + ("0000" & c_in); 
    if(sum_temp > 9) then
        c_out <= '1';
        sum <= resize((sum_temp + "00110"),4);
    else
        c_out <= '0';
        sum <= sum_temp(3 downto 0);
    end if;  
end process;   
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity final_adder is
    port(a_final1,a_final2,b_final1,b_final2 : in  unsigned(3 downto 0);
         c_in_final : in std_logic;
         sum_final1,sum_final2  : out  unsigned(3 downto 0); 
         c_out_final : inout std_logic);
end final_adder;
architecture final of final_adder is
component bcd_adder1
    port(a,b : in  unsigned(3 downto 0);
         c_in : in std_logic;
         sum  : out  unsigned(3 downto 0); 
         c_out : out std_logic);
end component;
begin
z0:bcd_adder1 port map(a_final1,b_final1,c_in_final,sum_final1,c_out_final);
z1:bcd_adder1 port map(a_final2,b_final2,c_out_final,sum_final2,c_out_final);
end final;
```

Please help!

Comment: To find out where you are wrong in this, write a testbench and simulate it.

Comment: If you use `std_ulogic_vector` and `u_unsigned` (aka `unresolved_unsigned`) types, instead of these resolved ones, you would not have this simulation behavior. It would already give an error during compilation, due to multiple drivers.